# Related to Taylor series of the natural log.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to prove the Taylor series for the natural logarithm.

We know that $$\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}=\ln x$$
Hence if I can know what is the Taylor Series for $1/t$ for $t>1$ I can solve the Taylor series for the natural log by integrating both sides, this is my Attempt:

Let $f(t)=1/t$ for $t>1$ and note that $f(1)=1$
$$\frac{1}{t}=f(1)+f^{(1)}(1)(t-1)+\frac{f^{(2)}(1)(t-1)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{f^{(3)}(1)(t-1)^{3}}{3!}+...$$
$$\frac{1}{t}=1-(t-1)+(t-1)^2-(t-1)^3+...$$
$$\int_{1}^x\frac{dt}{t}=t-\frac{(t-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(t-1)^3}{3}-\frac{(t-1)^4}{4}+...\Bigr\rvert_{1}^x$$
$$\ln x=(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}-\frac{(x-1)^4}{4}+..$$
I am sure that i didn't make any mistake, the problem is when i searched for the Taylor series of natural log on wikipedia i didn't found this formula, so Am i wrong?

Comment: The integration variable cannot be equal to the upper (or lower)  bound in the integral.

Comment: why not ? @Bernard

Comment: You should write something like $$\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ since $x$ cannot be an integration variable and a "normal" variable at the same time.

Comment: @Yassir: The variable inside the integral is a dummy variable. Consider how $$\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt = \int_{a}^{b} f(u) \, du = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(\alpha) \, d\alpha \, .$$The variable outside the integral (here, $x$) is not. It makes sense to plug in a number for one of the upper bounds of the integral, but it does not make sense to do so for the dummy variable inside. You're using $x$ in two different ways.

Comment: Because the $x$ under the integral sign is a *dummy* variable.

Comment: i edited the question, but is this formula correct?

Comment: Now, it is correct.

Comment: But why Wikipedia doesn't use it? it does use something like $ln(1+x)$ and $ln(1-x)$

Comment: It gives $\ln \left(1+x\right)$ for $x$ being near to $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also assume the form $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\ $ and try to calculate the coefficients of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ given that $f$ verifies the ODE: $$(x+1)f'(x)=1$$

$\begin{align}(x+1)\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)'
&=(x+1)\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}
=a_1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (na_n+(n+1)a_{n+1})x^{n}\end{align}$

Identifying with the constant series $1$ we get

$\begin{cases}a_1=1\\na_n+(n+1)a_{n+1}=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a_1=1\\a_{n+1}=-\dfrac {n}{n+1}a_n\end{cases}$

$\require{cancel}a_n=\left(-\frac{\cancel{n-1}}{n}\right)\left(-\frac{\cancel{n-2}}{\cancel{n-1}}\right)\left(-\frac{\cancel{n-3}}{\cancel{n-2}}\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{\cancel{2}}\right)a_1=(-1)^{n-1}\times\dfrac 1n$

We have also $a_0=f(0)=\ln(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arose in your calculations
$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}=\ln x$$

Let $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ for $t>1$
$$\frac{1}{t}=f(1)+f^{'}(1)(t-1)+\frac{f^{"}(1)(t-1)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{f^{'"}(1)(t-1)^{3}}{3!}+\dots \dots $$
$$\frac{1}{t}=1-1(t-1)+\frac{2(t-1)^2}{2}-\frac{6(t-1)^3}{6}+ \dots \dots$$

$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}=1-1(t-1)+\frac{2(t-1)^2}{2}-\frac{6(t-1)^3}{6}+\frac{24(t-1)^4}{24}+\dots \dots \Bigr\rvert_{1}^{x}$$
$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}=1-1(t-1)+(t-1)^2-(t-1)^3+(t-1)^4+\dots \dots \Bigr\rvert_{1}^{x}$$
$$In( x )= (x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}-\frac{(x-1)^4}{4}+\dots $$
$$In (1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{6} \dots $$
you should also try this $\frac{1}{1-x}$ because you don't need Taylor series here, long division will do it
$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots \dots$$
You can integrate to see that,
$$-In(1-x) = x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\dots \dots $$

$$In (1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{6} \dots $$
Combining this two gives the super $\log()$ series, because it has no restrictions and converges faster